# How can I map an array with duplicate values to a unique array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following array:

```
var tst = 
[
 {"topicId":1,"subTopicId":1,"topicName":"a","subTopicName":"w"},
 {"topicId":1,"subTopicId":2,"topicName":"b","subTopicName":"x"},
 {"topicId":1,"subTopicId":3,"topicName":"c","subTopicName":"y"},
 {"topicId":2,"subTopicId":4,"topicName":"c","subTopicName":"z"}
]
```

Is there an easy way that I can map that to this kind of array where topicId > id and topicName > name:

```
var t = 
[
  {"id":1,"name":"a"},
  {"id":2,"name":"c"}
]
```

I am using a modern browser and I also have _lodash if that helps. Note that there will be about 100 rows in the tst array so I don't need a very optimized solution. A simple and easy to maintain solution would be more important.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/what-is-the-most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-javascript-array-of-objects

Comment: Wow I just looked at that link. Very much code. I wonder if there is a simpler lodash solution.

Comment: what do you mean by "topicId > id and topicName > name". topicName and name are string and cannot be greater than or less than one another..?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**MOST RECENT**

[_.uniqBy is now preferable](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#uniqBy)

[Full working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/5q35ea1m/)

```
var tst = [
 {"topicId":1,"subTopicId":1,"topicName":"a","subTopicName1":"w"},
 {"topicId":2,"subTopicId":2,"topicName":"b","subTopicName2":"x"},
 {"topicId":3,"subTopicId":3,"topicName":"c","subTopicName3":"y"},
 {"topicId":1,"subTopicId":4,"topicName":"c","subTopicName4":"z"}
];

var result = _.map(_.uniqBy(tst, 'topicId'), function (item) {
    return {
        id: item.topicId,
        name: item.topicName
    };  
});

console.log(result);
```

---

**LEGACY**

http://lodash.com/docs#uniq is a good start

```
_.uniq([{ 'x': 1 }, { 'x': 2 }, { 'x': 1 }], 'x');
```

Your code would look like this to get topics unique by id

```
var t = _.uniq(tst, 'topicId');
```

**EDIT**

I made a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/q5HNw/

**UPDATE**

Removed unnecessary uniqueness of names

http://jsfiddle.net/q5HNw/1/

Comment: can you give me an example using the code I have. I am not quite sure how I could change the field names when I look at your example.

Comment: The topicName is ALWAYS the same for each topicID. So could this be made more simple with just one _.uniq check ?

Comment: Yes, just throw away the instruction with `_.uniq(t, 'name')`, I'll update my answer and the jsfiddle

Comment: This failed to recognize unique topic names? At least my test failed.

Comment: @Melina I think I misunderstood your point, you must use uniq to filter by topicName, because a topic with an id X and a name Y could have an id W but a name Y too

Answer (score 2):

I am one of those guys that use native functions :)

```
var results = tst.reduce(function(res,topic){
var exists = res.some(function(t){ return (t.id === topic.topicId && t.name === topic.topicName);});        
     if (!exists){
        res.push({"id": topic.topicId, "name": topic.topicName});
     }
return res; },[]);
```

**Lodash version**

I am not an expert using lodash, probably I will try something like this:

```
var results = _.reduce(tst, function(res, topic){       
    var exists = _.findIndex(res, function(t){
        return (t.id === topic.topicId && t.name === topic.topicName);
    });
    if (exists === -1){
      res.push({"id": topic.topicId, "name": topic.topicName});
    }
    return res; 
},[]);
```

Comment: But I already have lodash used for other things. I am wondering if this would be easier given the small number of records I have and the fact this is not needed frequently. Just thinking it might be easier to maintain with lodash.

Comment: @Melina I translated to the original post to lodash

Answer (score -1):

#### Using ECMAScript 2015 `Array.prototype.find()`

The [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.

```js
let tst = [
     {"topicId":1,"subTopicId":1,"topicName":"a","subTopicName":"w"},
     {"topicId":1,"subTopicId":2,"topicName":"b","subTopicName":"x"},
     {"topicId":1,"subTopicId":3,"topicName":"c","subTopicName":"y"},
     {"topicId":2,"subTopicId":4,"topicName":"c","subTopicName":"z"},
];

let t = [];
tst.forEach(obj => {
  // Check if the id already exists in the array 't'
  if (!t.find((self) => self.id === obj.topicId)) {
    // If not, pushes obj to t
    t.push({
      id: obj.topicId,
      name: obj.topicName
    });
  }
});

console.log(t);
```

You can also compare more than one property:

```js
let tst = [
         {"topicId":1,"subTopicId":1,"topicName":"a","subTopicName":"w"},
         {"topicId":1,"subTopicId":2,"topicName":"b","subTopicName":"x"},
         {"topicId":1,"subTopicId":3,"topicName":"c","subTopicName":"y"},
         {"topicId":2,"subTopicId":4,"topicName":"c","subTopicName":"z"},
];


let t = [];
tst.forEach(obj => {
  // Check if the 'id' and 'subId' already exist in t 
  if (!t.find((self) => self.id === obj.topicId && self.subId === obj.subTopicId)) {
    // If not, pushes obj to t
    t.push({
      id: obj.topicId,
      subId: obj.subTopicId,
      name: obj.topicName
    });
  }
});

console.log(t);
```